# Mod_rewrite, check if string is empty

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to write a .htaccess file to rewrite all urls which have anyting after the domain.

For example `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=course&course=$1 [L]`

But this sends `example.com` to that rewritten url as well, and I don't want that. I want it to rewrtire it ONLY if these is really something after the domain, like `example.com/CITA180`.

I know that I could do `example.com/c/CITA180` and then do `RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ index.php?page=course&course=$1 [L]` but I don't want to do it like that if I don't have to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.+` instead of `.*` to make sure it doesn't match landing page. You will also need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition to avoid matching default landing page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=course&course=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add regex condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} REGEX`

In your case: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [A-Z]`
This will check if it contains any character or not.

Along with not a file check: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`